# pip: command 'install' has no such option 'pre_commands'

Tags: python, pip, installation

I have this error when running any `pip install [--user] <package>` or `virtualenv <path>` command in a specific directory:

```
DistutilsOptionError: error in setup.cfg: command 'install' has no such option 'pre_commands'
```

How do I fix this error and allow packages to be installed again?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the current directory contains python setup files which confuse `distutils`.
The solution is to move `setup.cfg` and `setup.py` away, for example

```sh
mv setup.py setup.py.tmp || true
mv setup.cfg setup.cfg.tmp || true
pip install foo
mv setup.py.tmp setup.py || true
mv setup.cfg.tmp setup.cfg || true
```